# Is there any full Python webdriver API documentation?

Tags: python, webdriver

I'm starting out using Selenium 2/Webdriver, been using Selenium IDE for a few weeks, to automate some tests and decided to go with Python. I've been writing some simple tests using some basic documentation that I found: http://readthedocs.org/docs/selenium-python/en/latest/index.html

While this documentation is good to start off, I noticed it's missing a lot of other commands that I'm used to using with Selenium IDE, such as verifying and asserting text/elements. Eventually I'd like to put some conditionals in my tests, so being able to do an assert and seeing if that returned true or false would be helpful, but I have no idea how to do that.

Is there any detailed documentation online?

Comment: Previously, I found nothing helpful so just used a combination of the Java documentation, web examples and built-in docstrings to try and work it out; but thanks for pointing this out, it's the most comprehensive documentation I've seen yet.

Comment: Yeah, I ran into the same problem. You can, however, obtain the Python library and run pydoc on it. The comments are in there; unfortunately the Selenium Python documentation is not autogenerated and published :(

Answer (score 5):

As it happens, that isn't (as far as I can tell) the official documentation,
which is here: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/index.html
(Link is dead)

Official documentation is here : https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html

(And which does have the full API reference.)

Answer (score 1):

There is an documentation provided [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) by Balaji Muthukundan. This is not an official one but it is pretty detailed and systematic. I often refer this documentation for any help regarding Selenium API's.

Comment: Could you please share the link? Thanks!

Comment: The link is in the answer itself